# Frequency specific GCC-PHAT

Tags: localization

## Background

[Python GCC-PHAT](https://github.com/xiongyihui/tdoa/blob/a52505672f15b50f1c07606e6609bb1cb016add8/gcc_phat.py#L21) works for me really well in a quiet environment.
However, in a noisy environment, the results are no good. I want to locate a source of the sound of a known frequency range between `x` and `y` in a noisy environment.

## The question

How can GCC-PHAT work on specific frequencies?

## What I tried

In the [gcc_phat](https://github.com/xiongyihui/tdoa/blob/a52505672f15b50f1c07606e6609bb1cb016add8/gcc_phat.py#L21) I zeroed-out all but the frequencies between `x` and `y`. However, this zeroed out the `tau` result of `gcc_phat` function.

Comment: Generally speaking zeroing-out frequency bins is not a very clever thing to do. Zeroing out in the frequency domain can result in very long ringing in the time domain, which will result in time aliasing if you haven't zero-padded sufficiently in advance. This can ruin your DoA estimation results from either GCC-PhaT or ANY other algorithm. I suggest you use proper (band-pass) filtering prior to feeding the data to the algorithm, like it is suggested in at an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since your sound source has a known frequency range, I would recommend a pre-filtering for noise reduction before DOA estimation.

You can use a bandpass filter with the specific frequency range, and then put the filtered signals into GCC-PHAT algorithm.